# Resume TrueCrypt encryption on another computer?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

Right now I have an 8TB drive that has 7 days left on it to encrypt it.
I want to take the drive with me to another physical location and resume encryption on another PC.

How can one do that?
Truecrypt will not see the drive as partially done.

Comment: Even with overwriting the drive, TrueCrypt shouldn't take more than a few hours to format it for TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt, not overwriting should take minutes, and they have clients for different OS'es, just another computer should be no problem. Why doesn't it work for you? And why are there only "7 days left"?

Answer (score 0):

Encryption on another device will not be possible

Comment: Why? Any source, link or explanation to support this?

Comment: This is incorrect. I was able to continue encryption on a different computer. I selected the option to resume encryption and it remembered where it left last time.